# how to print u32string and u16string to the console in c++

Tags: c++, string

I recently bumped into string literals and found some new strings like u16string and u32string. I found that wstring can be printed to the console using std::wcout, but that doesn't work for u16string or u32string. How can i print these to the Console??

Comment: See this ---------------------> https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594382/5323912

Comment: ©N1gthm4r3 codecvt is deprecated in C++17.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the below code would work, but note that `<codecvt>` is deprecated in c++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
  std::u16string str = u"sample";
  
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
  std::cout << converter.to_bytes(str) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Maybe something like this could work as well,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::u16string str(u"abcdefg");
  for (const auto& c: str)
    std::cout << static_cast<char>(c);
}
```

Not sure how robust the latter is, and how efficient you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

@Burgers' solution works in clang 12.0.0 (macOS Catalina XCode)

Note that for u32string you need to use char32_t.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  u32string str = u"很有用";  // btw. str.size() == 4
  
  wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> converter;

  cout << converter.to_bytes(str) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```